# Image not change in android

Tags: android, image

I have application for read database. The code work perfecly but when I use `if .. then ... else` for ImageView it's not work. May be I'm work with my code. Anyone can help me to fix my code?

My Screen Shoot Application http://prntscr.com/beuid8

My code like this

```
Toolbar toolbar;
ImageView image;
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

private ListView listView;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.1.111/log_inputitem.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "inputitemlog";
private static final String TAG_LOGO = "Item Logo";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";
private static final String TAG_CODEITEM = "Item Code";
private static final String TAG_UPGRADEITEM = "Item Upgrade";
private static final String TAG_DATEITEM = "Item Date";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_logitem);
    // ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
    TypedValue typedValueColorPrimaryDark = new TypedValue();
    ListLogItem.this.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValueColorPrimaryDark, true);
    final int colorPrimaryDark = typedValueColorPrimaryDark.data;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(colorPrimaryDark);
    }
}

// Get listview
protected ListView getListView(){
    if (listView == null) {
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.logitem);
    }
    return listView;
}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListLogItem.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String logo = c.getString(TAG_LOGO);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String codeitem = c.getString(TAG_CODEITEM);
                    String upgradeitem = c.getString(TAG_UPGRADEITEM);
                    String dateitem = c.getString(TAG_DATEITEM);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_LOGO, logo);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_CODEITEM, codeitem);
                    map.put(TAG_UPGRADEITEM, upgradeitem);
                    map.put(TAG_DATEITEM, dateitem);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Doesn't have log item now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        //runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        // public void run() {
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                ListLogItem.this, productsList,
                R.layout.list_inputitem, new String[]{
                TAG_LOGO, TAG_NAME, TAG_CODEITEM, TAG_UPGRADEITEM, TAG_DATEITEM},
                new int[]{R.id.thumbnail, R.id.title, R.id.rating, R.id.genre, R.id.releaseYear});
        if (TAG_LOGO == "ig"){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.flat);
        }
        // updating listview
        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
        //}
        // });
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_news, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Anyone can help me to make my ImageView work?
Thanks before

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're getting the name of the image properly, but because those images names aren't anywhere in your app (this is my guess) SimpleAdapter doesn't have a Resource Id to be matched to them; If you're receiving an image name like "pretty_car.png", and you're passing that to the SimpleAdapter, it doesn't matter anything for it, doesn't know which image from the resources should be loaded from the app content. Your only option seems to be create a custom Adapter that retrieves the images based on its file name.